# Customize WordPress search to include posts that contain the search result a post tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that I am trying to edit with no luck.

I want to be able to include posts that may have the search term *s* as a post tag.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','modify_search');
function modify_search($query)
{
if ($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_search() && !is_admin()) {

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {

        $query->set('s', sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']));

        $query->set('post_type', sanitize_text_field($_GET['post_type']));

    }

}
```

}

I have tried multiple different ways of setting the “tax_query” parameter for the query with no luck .

The goal is to be able to list all posts and cpts that may have the search term in their title, content or excerpts, but also any posts that contain the search term as a post tag

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

```
function custom_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
    $tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $query->query_vars['s'],
        ),
    );

    // Debugging output
    error_log(print_r($tax_query, true));

    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
}
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_filter');
```

Updated to provide one of the many different ways I have tried going about this.

I don’t want to change the default method of the search looking at the title, content or excerpt, I just want to hook into the search and ALSO display any posts that might contain the search term provided.

I’ll add I also have a form with checkboxes that I filter the results based on cpt’s but that’s irrelevant to this task

Comment: Since the `tax_query` parameter is the main problem could you please add one of the `tax_query` attempts to your question?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear on the issue: You want to include both any posts whose content (ie: Title and Content) match the search term, as well as any posts whose tag names also match the search term, correct?

Comment: @maiorano84 correct

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL-speak, the question is asking for a UNION of two queries. WordPress does not handle this natively. An experimental WordPress plugin exists for this task: [Combine Query](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries#combine-query).

The code in the solution below has been tested. It uses native WordPress hooks and functions.

The solution consists of these steps:

1. use `posts_results` filter hook to update the default search result list of posts,
2. use `WP_Query` to generate a secondary query for the tag-filtered list of posts,
3. combine the two lists,
4. remove duplicates, and
5. sort the final result.

### posts_results

The [posts_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_results/) filter hook is used to update the list of posts produced from the default search result. WordPress documentation says it: *Filters the raw post results array, prior to status checks.*

#### Warning!

WordPress documentation says:

> The input of this filter is an array of posts, created by any(?) WP_Query looking for posts.

You should prepare for *any* use of WP_Query *anywhere* in WordPress (core, theme, child theme, third party plugins, blocks, widgets, etc.) to be affected by this filter. Assuming you limit its use with conditional tags like `is_search` and `is_admin`, the `posts_results` filter hook should only be applied to the search (results) page. So, all blocks, widgets, etc. on the search page that use WP_Query directly or indirectly could be affected by this filter.

#### Infinite loop

Since WP_Query is used for a secondary query, and *any* use of WP_Query triggers the `posts_results` filter hook, there is a risk of an infinite loop. To avoid this problem, the `posts_results` callback should be removed before calling `new WP_Query`, and re-added after using WP_Query. Use of conditional tags in an if-statement make callback removal and re-addition unnecessary in the `my_posts_search_results_filter` function below. But, care should be taken to prevent these infinite loops.

### WP_Query

The WordPress documentation says this about the WP_Query [post_type parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters):

> [The] default value is 'post'. If 'tax_query' is set for a query, the default value becomes 'any';

However, testing showed that using `tax_query` in the secondary query does not produce posts from custom post types when `post_type` is omitted. So, `post_type` must be included among the secondary query parameters, and any desired custom post types must be explicitly listed.

### Sorting

As with SQL UNION, ordering is done after the lists are combined. [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort) is used to sort the combined list in descending order by `post_date` (i.e. most recent posts first).

## Solution

```
/**
 * Sort WP_Post objects in reverse order (most recent first).
 *
 * @param string $key WP_Post object property used for sorting. 'post_date' is assumed.
 *
 * @return int
 */
function post_sort( $key ) {
    return function ( $a, $b ) use ( $key ) {
        if ( $a->$key < $b->$key ) {
            return 1;
        } elseif ( $a->$key > $b->$key ) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            // If first comparison is equal, use title as secondary sort key.
            return strnatcasecmp( $a->post_title, $b->post_title );
        }
    };
}


/**
 * Remove duplicate posts in combined list from default and secondary queries.
 *
 * @param array  $posts Array of WP_Post objects.
 * @param string $key   Search key used to identify duplicate objects. Post ID is used
 *
 * @return array
 */
function dedupe( $posts, $key ) {
    $unique_posts = array();
    $ids = array();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $post->$key, $ids ) ) {
            $ids[] = $post->$key;
            $unique_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    return $unique_posts;
}


/**
 * posts_results filter hook callback.
 *
 * @param array  $posts Array of WP_Post objects.
 * @param object $query WP_Query object from default search.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_posts_search_results_filter( $posts, $query ) {
    if ( \is_search() && $query->is_search() && ! \is_admin() ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $query->get( 's' )
                )
            )
        );

        // Remove callback to avoid infinite loop.
        \remove_filter( 'posts_results', 'my_posts_search_results_filter', 10 );
        $secondary_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
        $tagged_posts = $secondary_query->get_posts();

        // Combine default search results with secondary query.
        $all_posts = array_merge( $posts, $tagged_posts );

        // Remove duplicate posts.
        $unique_posts = dedupe( $all_posts, 'ID' );

        // Sort by reverse post_date order (most recent first).
        usort( $unique_posts, post_sort( 'post_date' ) );

        // Restore posts_results callback.
        \add_filter( 'posts_results', 'my_posts_search_results_filter', 10, 2 );

        return $unique_posts;
    } else {
        return $posts;
    }   
}


\add_filter( 'posts_results', 'my_posts_search_results_filter', 10, 2 );
```